# a more elegant way to do this?

Tags: ruby, methods, scope

Sorry that I haven't made the title very clear but I honestly can't work out how to phrase my question any better; if some one can think of a better title, then please by all means change it.

Take a look at the following example:

```
module Foo
  def method(value)
    Bar.instance_exec(self.method(value))
  end

  class Bar

    def self.method(value)
      print value
    end

  end
end
```

Is that the only way to make is so  `Bar`'s `method` is available within the namespace of `Foo` without the need to call `Bar` or is there a more elegant way to do this? Perhaps method_missing might work but again, a bit cumbersome.

EDIT:
Further example

```
Module Foo
  class SomeClassController < ApplicationController

   def index
    method(@user.id) #instead of Bar.method(@user.id)
  end

end
```

I'm building an engine but I don't want to have to refer to `Engine` every time I want to use a method from it that should be available everywhere within that Main Name Space (`Foo` in this instance) AS there more like utility methods BUT they need to be done within the scope of `Engine`.

EDIT:
Turns out I wasn't using the code correctly

```
module Foo
  def method(value)
    return Bar.instance_exec(value) { |v| return self.method(value)}
  end

  class Bar

    def self.method(value)
      return (value + 59)
    end

  end
end
```

will the method inside of the block of `instance_exec` return outside of it so that `def method` within `module Foo` will return the correct value.

EDIT: I realise it is kind of vague but trust me when I say that `instance_exec` is exactly what I was searching for, that and `instance_exec` does in deed return outside of it's execution block.

Comment: Please give an example, including the desired result.

Comment: You can just call `Bar.method value`

Comment: quick question, if you invoke a method using instance exec, does the method return to the scope that called instance exec? For example would `Bar.instance_exec(self.method(value)) return a value that can be used within `Foo`'s `method` or does the value that returns from the method stay within it's execution scope? Which is `Bar`.

Comment: I still don't understand your question, and judging from the interest expressed by others, I don't think I'm alone.  For a question like this you need to say, "Here's my code.  I executed this statement .... and got this result .... but wanted this result .... What did I do wrong?".  Or, "Here's my code.  I want to execute this statement.... and get this result.... How do I do that?"  That's why I asked for an example.

Comment: What I was trying to do (now that I know what it's called) is change the execution context of that code, kind like rails has functions that can be just called out of context (so long as you use a macro like `helper_method`) I wanted to know how to do the same thing and I do; I use `instance_exec(value)`. The other reason I needed it this way was that the class that I was using for the execution context had extra functions included in it that I didn't want to include more then once and I needed access to it's properties to execute said code in a DRY way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem is as follows using a rails engine as the example to add a more understandable context

engine.rb:

```
module Foo

 class Engine

    class SomeClass

      def method(value)
        return (value + 59)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

otherActions.rb

```
module Foo

  def method(value)
    return Engine.instance_exec(value){ |v|  return self::SomeClass.method(v) }
  end

end
```

Engine_Controller.rb

```
Module Foo

  class EngineController < ApplicationController.rb

    def index
      @user.some_field = method(params[:user_input])
    end

  end
end
```

I think that should work well, I know everything Up to the usage of `method` within `def index` at least, that I'm not sure about but the main point of the question has been answered within otherActions.rb